# Where can I compile the opengl source to generate libraries?

Tags: qt, opengl

Where can I find a program which can be executed on Visual studio to compile openGL sources and generate libraries like opengl32.lib, glut32.lib, etc. In fact I have a problem of version with QT. I want to execute opengl using QT but without QT Opengl API.

Here's the error message :

```
lnk2026 module unsafe for safeseh image opengl32.lib
```

I'm really lost.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

OpenGL is a specification, not a library with a defined source code. OpenGL implementations are what you use, and most of them are propietary. Some of them are open source (such as MESA), but in general you do not have public access to the source code.

Answer (score 1):

The "Open" in "OpenGL" refers to the nature of the specification, not to the concept of "open source". OpenGL is "Open" in that the specification is freely available and can be implemented by anyone (modulo patent claims).

So while you can compile free-standing implementations of OpenGL, what your operating system provides (in your case, via `opengl32.lib` and `opengl32.dll`) is *not* something you can compile yourself.